# SMPS for AC-DC conversion

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ac-dc

The question is related to datasheet of part DK1203.

The [datasheet](https://grupoautcomp.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Specification-IC-DK1203.pdf) description is as follows:

> The DK1203 is a secondary side flyback type AC-DC Switch Mode Power Controlling IC. With integrated 700V high voltage power transistor,patented self-power supply circuit and integrated MOS circuit design, lots of external components are saved, transformer design is simple, only two windings is needed for the transformer in isolated output circuit

The datasheet for this part contains this diagram:

[image]

It seems that first we convert AC-DC using bridge rectifier and capacitor and then DC-AC using tansformer and switching circuit inside the IC1. Then we convert it back AC to DC using capacitors and diode D6. There are a few things that are not clear. I shall be grateful if someone can help in deciphering them.

1. We don't we use transformer to step down voltage from 12V to a smaller value, and then apply AC-DC conversion step just once? I am quite confused by this continuos conversion between AC and DC.
2. What is purpose of capacitor C1, Y1 and inductor L1?

The feedback mechanism using opto-isolated parts in IC2 along with ZD1 is quite interesting. I shall first try to decipher this myself before I ask here.

I am electronic engineer myself so you do not need to explain things in too much detail.

Comment: I am not sure if this is for a self-learning or industrial project, but I would *stay away* from this unknown brand considering the poorly-written data-sheet: no temperature information at all, no characterization curves and really goofy design procedure. There are plenty of other reputable brands to choose from if you need a high-voltage switcher.

Comment: I saw this in a youtube video, I agree that the brand and datasheet gives a very bad sensation.

Answer (score 3):

Comparatively small transformer [inductor-transformer in case of this flyback] is the reason for rectifying AC to DC on the mains side, then chopping it again, and rectifying it again on the secondary side of the transformer.  The switching frequency for this IC is 65 kHz.  Most off-line converters work at frequencies around 50 kHz to 250 kHz.  Transformers, inductors, capacitors needed for these frequencies are smaller than for 60 Hz mains frequencies.  As a result, a 20W modern flyback (including the EMC filter) AC-DC can be smaller and lighter than a 20W 60Hz transformer.

> What is purpose of capacitor C1 ?

R1 C1 and D5 form a [snubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber) circuit.

> What is purpose of capacitor Y1 ?

Y1 provides a high frequency return path from secondary side to mains side, which reduces EMI.  Y1 is a safety rated capacitor.

> What is purpose of capacitor L1 ?

L1 and EC4 are an LC filter which reduces output ripple.

Comment: This SMPS is different from TPS62903-Q1 which is a buck converter for DC-DC conversion. Since this is not a buck converter, what is it?

Comment: It’s mentioned many times - it’s a flyback converter. Similar to a boost converter, but using a coupled inductor (aka transformer) to extract the output power and scale the voltage.